# Showing one singular total for a time series bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, label, bar-chart, subplot

I have output of some code I ran that looks as follows:

[image]

What I am looking to do is add a total **not above each individual bar**  but below the subhead in the chart - example below phone so 61 in the email chart to show the end user what all the tiny lines sum to. I was hoping to do this without adding a scalar value and having to update the code all the time (e.g. plt.text('61',etc.))

code I use to run is as follows for charts

```
phone_contact = master_frame[(master_frame.contactmethod=='Phone')]['Date'].value_counts()
email_contact = master_frame[(master_frame.contactmethod=='E-mail')]['Date'].value_counts()
mail_contact = master_frame[(master_frame.contactmethod=='Mail')]['Date'].value_counts()
all_contact = master_frame['Date'].value_counts()

#Volume by inbound channel
plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,4, sharex=True)
x=90

axs[0].bar(phone_contact.index, phone_contact)
axs[0].set_title('Phone Contact')
axs[0].tick_params(labelrotation=x)
axs[0].set_ylim(0, 25)

axs[1].bar(email_contact.index, email_contact, color="green", width=0.5)
axs[1].set_title('Email Contact')
axs[1].tick_params(labelrotation=x)
axs[1].set_ylim(0, 25)

axs[2].bar(mail_contact.index,mail_contact, color='cyan')
axs[2].set_title('Mail Contact')
axs[2].tick_params(labelrotation=x)
axs[2].set_ylim(0, 25)

axs[3].bar(all_contact.index,all_contact, color='red')
axs[3].set_title('All Contacts')
axs[3].tick_params(labelrotation=x)
axs[3].set_ylim(0, 25)

plt.suptitle('Interaction')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

snippet of data I use to run looks like this:

*INTERACTION DATE,  INTERACTION ADDED BY,   Contact method,
11/1/2023,  rep 1,  Phone,
11/1/2023,  rep 2,  Phone,
11/1/2023,  rep 3,  Phone,
11/1/2023,  rep 4,  E-mail,
11/1/2023,  rep 5,  Phone,
11/1/2023,  rep 6,  Mail,
11/2/2023,  rep 7,  Phone,
11/2/2023,  rep 8,  E-mail,
11/2/2023,  rep 9,  Phone,
11/2/2023,  rep 10, Phone,
11/2/2023,  rep 11, E-mail,
11/2/2023,  rep 12, E-mail,
11/2/2023,  rep 1,  Phone,
11/2/2023,  rep 2,  E-mail,
11/2/2023,  rep 3,  Phone,
11/3/2023,  rep 4,  Phone,
11/3/2023,  rep 5,  Phone,
11/3/2023,  rep 6,  Phone,
11/3/2023,  rep 7,  E-mail,
11/3/2023,  rep 8,  E-mail,
11/3/2023,  rep 9,  Phone,
11/3/2023,  rep 10, E-mail,
11/3/2023,  rep 11, Phone,
11/6/2023,  rep 12, Phone*

I have tried plt.annotate method as well as plt.text but (rightfully so) both work towards labelling the individual bars whereas I just want on total number in the top middle of the graph (i.e. "61"). I have looks through a number of examples and can't come across anything that addresses specifically this. Help is appreciated.